# Angular http.get petition error 401 no authoritzation

Tags: angular, get, angular2-routing, frontend

I try send petition GET to server, but he return me 401 - No Authorization. On postman I use the same route but use basic auth with my name and user. In Angular I try send my authoritzation using header but always I recived 401. This is my code: any ideea? Thanks to all. Sorry for my bad english.

```
  public get(route, skipToken?: boolean) {
    const me = this;

    let options;
    if (!skipToken) {
        options = {
            headers:  {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Basic myuser:mypswd',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'withCredentials': 'true',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Authorization'},
            search: me.getSearchParamToken()
        };
    } else {
        options = {
            headers:  {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
                'Authorization': 'Basic myuser:mypswd',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'withCredentials': 'true', 
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Authorization'}
        };
    }
    return me.http.get(route, options).map(response => response.json() || {}).catch(me.handleError);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your server uses HTTP basic auth? And you are using correct credentials for authentication ?

Comment: Hi @Rohan I using postman with the same user and password and don't have problems. If postman works, the problem is my code? thanks

Comment: Please verify whether you have selected any encoding option in postman. May be server needs your credentials in encoded format and postman is doing it internally. Bcoz code seems to be correct for GET calls.

Comment: @Rohan Actuality I view header and postman convert user and password in base64? I try with this code and don't work.... It's possible view all headers? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try following way to pass the Base64 encoded header.

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic '+btoa(username + ':' + password));
this.http.get(URL,headers);
```

Actually It will depend on how it is encoded on server side.
If any different encoding mechanism is used then it will change accordingly.
In order to check it out you can follow following steps :

1. Disable Base64 encoding in POSTMAN.
2. Hit with normal credentials so it generates 401 on POSTMAN.
3. Then try with btoa or [Base64](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-encode-and-decode-strings-with-base64-in-javascript) method and pass that encoded data using POSTMAN.
4. Once you come to know how it is done on server then you will simply change your code accordingly.